# Swiftui Tasks are not running in Parallel

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, concurrency

I have a problem running multiply tasks in parallel in a SwiftUI view.

```swift
struct ModelsView: View {
    @StateObject var tasks = TasksViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(Array(zip(tasks.tasks.indices, tasks.tasks)), id: \.0) { task in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ModelView()) {
                        ModelPreviewView(model_name: "3dobject.usdz")
                            .onAppear {
                                if task.0 == tasks.tasks.count - 2 {
                                    Task {
                                        print(tasks.tasks.count)
                                        await tasks.fetch_tasks(count: 4)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("3D modelle")
        }.onAppear{
            Task {
                await tasks.fetch_tasks(count: 5)
                await tasks.watch_for_new_tasks()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my view, I spawn a task as soon as the View Appears which, first, fetches 5 tasks from the database (this works fine), and then it starts watching for new tasks.

In the Scroll View, right before the bottom is reached, I start loading new tasks. The problem is, the asynchronous function fetch_tasks(count: 4) only gets continued if the asynchronous function watch_for_new_tasks() stops blocking.

```swift
actor TasksViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor @Published private(set) var tasks : [Tasks.Task] = []

    private var last_fetched_id : String? = nil

    func fetch_tasks(count: UInt32) async {
        do {
            let tasks_data = try await RedisClient.shared.xrevrange(streamName: "tasks", end: last_fetched_id ?? "+" , start: "-", count: count)
            last_fetched_id = tasks_data.last?.id
            let fetched_tasks = tasks_data.compactMap { Tasks.Task(from: $0.data) }

            await MainActor.run {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    self.tasks.append(contentsOf: fetched_tasks)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching taskss \(error)")
        }
    }

    func watch_for_new_tasks() async {
        while !Task.isCancelled {
            do {

                let tasks_data = try await RedisClient.shared.xread(streams: "tasks", ids: "$")
                let new_tasks = tasks_data.compactMap { Tasks.Task(from: $0.data) }

                await MainActor.run {
                    for new_task in new_tasks.reversed() {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.tasks.insert(new_task, at: 0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

The asynchronous function `watch_for_new_tasks()` uses `RedisClient.shared.xread(streams: "tasks", ids: "$")` which blocks until at least one tasks is added to the Redis Stream.

This is my redis client:

```swift
class RedisClient {
    typealias Stream = Array<StreamElement>
    
    static let shared = RedisClient(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379)
    
    let connection: Redis
    
    let host: String
    let port: Int32
    
    init(host: String, port: Int32) {
        connection = Redis()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        
        connection.connect(host: host, port: port) {error in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func connect() {
        connection.connect(host: self.host, port: self.port) {error in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func xrevrange(streamName: String, end: String, start: String, count: UInt32 = 0) async throws -> Stream {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            connection.issueCommand("xrevrange", streamName, end, start, "COUNT", String(count)) { res in
                switch res {
                case .Array(let data):
                    continuation.resume(returning: data.compactMap { StreamElement(from: $0) } )
                case .Error(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.RedisError(error))
                case _:
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.WrongData("Expected Array"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func xread(streams: String..., ids: String..., block: UInt32 = 0, count: UInt32 = 0) async throws -> Stream {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ continuation in
            var args = ["xread", "BLOCK", String(block),"COUNT", String(count),"STREAMS"]
            args.append(contentsOf: streams)
            args.append(contentsOf: ids)
            connection.issueCommandInArray(args){ res in
                print(res)
                switch res.asArray?[safe: 0]?.asArray?[safe: 1] ?? .Error("Expected response to be an array") {
                case .Array(let data):
                    continuation.resume(returning: data.compactMap { StreamElement(from: $0) } )
                case .Error(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.RedisError(error))
                case _:
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.WrongData("Expected Array"))
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    func xreadgroup(group: String, consumer: String, count: UInt32 = 0, block: UInt32 = 0, streams: String..., ids: String..., noAck: Bool = true) async throws -> Stream {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ continuation in
            var args = ["xreadgroup", "GROUP", group, consumer, "COUNT", String(count), "BLOCK", noAck ? nil : "NOACK", String(block), "STREAMS"].compactMap{ $0 }
            args.append(contentsOf: streams)
            args.append(contentsOf: ids)
            connection.issueCommandInArray(args){ res in
                print(res)
                switch res.asArray?[safe: 0]?.asArray?[safe: 1] ?? .Error("Expected response to be an array") {
                case .Array(let data):
                    continuation.resume(returning: data.compactMap { StreamElement(from: $0) } )
                case .Error(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.RedisError(error))
                case _:
                    continuation.resume(throwing: ResponseError.WrongData("Expected Array"))
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    enum ResponseError: Error {
        case RedisError(String)
        case WrongData(String)
    }
    
    struct StreamElement {
        let id: String
        let data: [RedisResponse]
        
        init?(from value: RedisResponse) {
            guard
                case .Array(let values) = value,
                let id = values[0].asString,
                let data = values[1].asArray
            else { return nil }
            
            self.id = id.asString
            self.data = data
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running the `watch_for_new_tasks()` on a `Task.detached` tasks, but that also blocks.

To be honest, I have no idea why this blocks, and I could use your guy's help if you could.

Thank you in Advance,

Michael

Comment: Look into TaskGroup

Comment: Hard reading code. Appending elements with animation?! on MainActor.run()? Need to use async let to run async functions in parallel.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

```
.onAppear {
            Task {
                await tasks.fetch_tasks(count: 5)
                await tasks.watch_for_new_tasks()
            }
        }
```

1. This does not run tasks in parallel. For the 2nd `await` to execute, the 1st one has to finish.
2. You can use `.task` modifier

You code can be refactored into this to run 2 async functions in parallel:

```
.task {
    async let fetchTask = tasks.fetch_tasks(count: 5)
    async let watchTask = tasks.watch_for_new_tasks()
}
```

You can do:

```
await [fetchTask, watchTask]
```

if you need to do something after both of them complete

Comment: This is not the Problem, this is intended. Those two should not run in parallel. The problem is thar the second fetch_tasks is blocking until watch_for_new_tasks stops blocking and continues its while loop.

Comment: You don’t need both actor and MainActor to make your code run in a thread safe environment. From the code above, you can use actor only. I believe your main problem is that you are appending in both functions on MainActor which represents main thread. You can try removing that and the with animation block, which is unnecessary.

Comment: That dosen't fix the problem, I have already tried that.